# HD 6770M low graphics mode after update (AGAIN)

Tags: graphics, ati, mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (re)installed on this [laptop](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c02767463&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN):

I've also installed the fglrx-drivers for my ATI card (using apt-get),it appeared to work fine,that is until i updated my distro.
Once again i got the "low graphics mode" error when i booted into the new kernel,booting in the old kernel works fine however.
When i look into the logs i see "no screen found".
This is the second time i install Ubuntu and the second time i run into problems with my graphics.

Reinstalling isn't a solution since the problem keeps comming back.
My question now is: does anyone know a REAL solution for this issue ar at least knows

what's causing it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What happens reinstalling only the ati driver again? Sometimes I have the same problem (Black Screen/Wrong resolution) So I go to shell and reinstall the display drivers. After reboot all works fine for me. 
I have to do this on every kernel update.
Maybe it can help you.